# Direct Connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 in Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sql-server-2012, connection

I have created a database with SQL server 2012, and i want to direct connect and access it from android application im developing in android studio.

I import jtds-1.3.1.java to project but is not connect.

and my code is :

```
public void query2()
{
    Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip_address:1433/DBname;";

        String username = "***";
        String password = "****";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
        Log.w("Connection","open");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from t1");
        while(reset.next()){
            txtData.setText(reset.getString(1));
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
        txtData.setText("Error in Connection");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add EasyWSDl plugin in android Studio
- create a package in main/java
- right-click on package and select EseayWSDL-add web service
- put asmx url